# Compilation problem while running the sdm package in Rstudio

Tags: compilation, package, rstudio

I am getting this error when compiling:

> Error in `FUN(X[[i]], ...)`: trying to get slot "presence" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the formula to see whether you are indicating the same name 
ie

```
sdmdata<- sdmData(**species~.,** train, test, predictors, bg..)
```

Writing this in the model will give you an error you described.

```
sdmmodel<- sdm(**specie~.,** data= methods=c("glm", "brt")).
```

I solved a similar problem that way